# How does setting battery level/status in the emulator settings GUI or over telnet differ from adb dumpsys battery set?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, battery

I'm trying to create an app that monitors battery levels, but since testing that in real time would be very cumbersome, I want to simulate different values and charging states through the emulator.

When I go into the emulator settings GUI by clicking "..." on the toolbar, then go to "Battery" and change values, it has no effect in the emulator. The OS' battery indicator always shows battery at 100% etc.

While researching I found two other ways to change the battery status:

Over telnet and over adb. Telnet matches the values that are set in the emulator settings GUI and vice versa, but doesn't change the actual values in the system. Both the battery status indicator and getting values using `batteryStatus.getIntExtra` etc stay unaffected.
Only using `adb shell dumpsys battery set level 20` gives the desired effect.

Why? What do telnet and the controls in the settings actually change then? Is there any way to make the settings actually work so I can change the battery levels and status over the emulators settings GUI?

I am using Android Studio 3.5.3 on Windows 10 and the emulator that comes with it with version 29.3.4-6110076, API 29.

Comment: I think for Windows 10 you need to go with PuTTY. http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Comment: Also, what is msg you get on hitting telnetting to emulator?

Comment: I installed telnet support for Windows 10 over the "Add/Remove Windows Features". After opening cmd.exe and telnetting I get "auth required" so I put in "auth <token>", then I get "OK" and when I input "power capacity 50" I also get "OK". But I don't even care about telnet, I want to be able to change the battery status over the emulator settings GUI, which isn't working, it's working ONLY over adb shell. Also tried PuTTY and after "auth <token>" it says "KO: Forbidden binary request. Aborting"

Answer (score 0):

Under Android Pie, the telnet route works (at least, it does for the relatively old AVD we use to test with) - it contacts the qemu system that forms the basis of the Android emulator, and you can set power capacity 20 or whatever. It seems that the GUI uses this route. These parameters are reflected by the `dumpsys battery` logic... until you start setting them through `dumpsys battery set` at which point dumpsys starts ignoring the qemu values.

Under Android 10, it appears only the adb commands take effect, so their tracking of the qemu parameters has been broken - I don't see any announcement about it, so I presume it's accidental.

If it no longer works in the GUI, then presumably nobody in the Emulator team told the GUI team they were planning to break the qemu route.

I notice that Android 10 emulates markedly slower than Pie, despite having fewer context switches at the CPU level, so presumably something deeper has changed, and the qemu linkage is a casualty.